# pgRouting cannot find route at intersection

Tags: pgrouting, network, route

I have a simple path that is defined by two polylines:
[image: Path defined by two polylines]

The first line goes from point 1 to point 2, and the second from 3 to 4. After running the `pgr_createTopology` script the source and target's values are consistent with that. The `pgr_analyzeGraph` returns the following results:

```
ANALYSIS RESULTS FOR SELECTED EDGES:
NOTICE:                    Isolated segments: 2
NOTICE:                            Dead ends: 4
NOTICE:  Potential gaps found near dead ends: 1
NOTICE:               Intersections detected: 1
NOTICE:                      Ring geometries: 0
```

My problem is when I try to run the `pgr_dijkstra` script. That only returns me a edge between the points (1,2) and the points (3,4). I can't get a result from 1 to 4 for example.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pgr_createTopology` does not "fix" disconnected graphs if two endpoints are not within a certain tolerance.

```
SELECT  pgr_createTopology('edge_table',0.001);
```

`0.001` in this example is the snapping tolerance and it's unit (meter or degree) is the same as the unit of your data.

`pgr_createTopology` never splits linestrings. It assumes, that there is no connection between your two line segments. So in your case you have to adjust your data.